# Issue while presenting new UINavigationController: under the StatusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

Firstly, I tried to present a custom `UIViewController` from another ViewController but I faced an issue with my new `UIViewController` displayed under the StatusBar.

Secondly, I decided to embed my custom `UIViewController` in a new `UINavigationController`, then present this navigation controller. But I faced the same issue with the StatusBar:

[image]

Here is my code for presenting the view:

```
MyCustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myCustomViewController"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; // I need nav bar to be hidden. Anyway,even if I don't hide it, the issue occur
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, here is MyCustomViewController in the storyboard:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Add layout screenshot of your myCustomViewController from storyboard.

Comment: @Bilal I edited my post with the storyboard screenshot! Is it ok?

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the constraints of the `Top Bar` view.